# SAS protect Excel worksheet with DDE

Tags: excel, sas, password-protection, dde

I want to manipulate an existing Excel sheet with DDE using SAS:

I have the following code (be careful! I use z for r(ows) and s for c(columns) because of German language settings in Excel):

```
option noxwait noxsync;
x call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office15\EXCEL.EXE";

%let delay=5;

data _null_;
rc=sleep(&delay); 
run;

filename sas2xl dde 'excel|system';

data _null_;
rc=sleep(&delay);
run;

%let mapwkbk=H:\odstest.xlsx;

data _null_;
file sas2xl;
rc=sleep(&delay);
put '[open("' "&mapwkbk" '")]';
run;


filename random dde 'excel|Daten!z2s1:z100s3';
data _null_;
    set sashelp.class;
    file random;
    put name sex age;
run;


data _null_;
file sas2xl;
/*rc=sleep(&delay);*/
put '[workbook.select("Pivot")]';
put '[select("Z2S1")]';
put "[pivot.refresh()]"; 

put '[workbook.select("Daten")]';
put '[select("z1S2:z1s5")]';
put '[filter]';
put '[select("z1S10")]';
put '[filter]';

put '[column.width(0,"s1",false,1)]';
put '[column.width(0,"s6:s9",false,1)]';

put '[ActiveSheet.Protect("***")]';

put '[workbook.delete("Dim")]';


/*put "[save()]";*/
/*put "[quit()]";*/
run;
```

Now I would like to password protect the sheet `Daten` and set option `use autofilter` active. Any ideas how to reach this?

Comment: If you really need this type of functionality I would strong suggest SAS Add In for Microsoft Office.

Comment: Unfortunately SAS AMO is not licensed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My recommendation here is to write a macro to do what you're trying to do (both questions here really), and then call that macro using DDE if you must use DDE.  That's far easier to do than to use DDE to do every little thing, and far easier to maintain (plus more portable when you eventually move away from DDE).

If you do that, then your macro code doesn't have all the extra SAS language bits around it, and can be more easily read/maintained (even by a VBA developer rather than a SAS developer), and SAS just calls the macro which is easy to do.

DDE is an old technology not well supported anymore, and new development should move away from it where possible.

Comment: Do you have a code example how to start a VBA macro with SAS? All I found did not work because VBA Macro is disabled in my environment. So I included a button to my Excel sheet, open it with DDE and then click the button to do the rest of the work.

Comment: If VBA Macros are disabled in your environment then of course the macros won't work.

Comment: @zuluk 100% agree with Joe on ditching DDE.  Move to any other solution you can find.  It's not longer supported and becoming more and more unreliable with each new version of windows.  In our current environment a single mandatory windows patch broke all DDE processes beyond repair so we were forced to migrate.  Don't be like me. On a separate note, you may find this useful: http://support.sas.com/kb/48/682.html